# Labelling equations as (r.1),(r.2),.. etc using \align

Tags: align, labels

I have a number of reaction equations, I would like to label them as `(r.1)`,`(r.2)`,... etc, using `\align`.

So we would have:

> equation 1      (r.1)
>
> equation 2      (r.2)
>
> equation 3      (r.3)
>
> equation 4      (r.4)

I would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: Would you please add a minimal working example of your code?  What packages are you currently using?

Comment: sounds like a slightly modified version of `subequations`

Comment: Have you tried `\renewcommand\theequation{r.\arabic{equation}`?

Comment: Sounds like a complete dupe to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147851 but as the question is not so clear, I wait to close.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi You are correct, go ahead, thanks for the link.

Comment: You are very welcome.