# How to force a special numbering with literals for a specific equation

Tags: numbering

As in [How to force a special numbering for a specific equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147851/64454) I want to introduce a set of chemical reactions (see code below) within a text containing some standard equations. Standard equations should be numbered continuously, but the chemical reactions should be numbered C1-Cn.

In addition to [hereinabove mentionned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147851/64454) problem I have two reactions below each other with the same product, so I'd like to get a numbering like C1a and C1b.

In equation-mode it is possible by introducing "subequations", see example below.
How can I do that? Thank you for your help!

This works:

```
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{equation}
     1 + 3 = 4
    \label{eq:1plus3}
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
     2 + 2 = 4 
    \label{eq:2plus2}
  \end{equation}
 \label{eq:result_equals_4}%
\end{subequations}
```

If I refer to this equations in my text, by using `\eqref{eq:1plus3}` I get (1.1a) and if I refer to `\eqref{eq:2plus2}` I get (1.1b), if I refer to `\eqref{eq:result_equals_4}` I get (1.1).

But this doesn't work:

```
\begin{subequations}
   \reaction[react:NO2_a]{2 NO + O_2 <=> 2 NO_2 + 114,2\,\mathrm{\frac{kJ}{mol}}}
   \reaction[react:NO2_b]{NO + O <=> NO_2 + 306,3\,\mathrm{\frac{kJ}{mol}}}
   \label{react:NO2}%
\end{subequations}
```

The result:

`\reref{react:NO2_a}` --> (C 1.1)

`\reref{react:NO2_b}` --> (C 1.2)

`\reref{react:NO2}` --> (1.20) (because I have 19 "standard, mathematical" equations)

I'd like to get:

`\reref{react:NO2_a}` --> (C 1.1a)

`\reref{react:NO2_b}` --> (C 1.1b)

`\reref{react:NO2}` --> (C 1.1)

Edit:

```
\documentclass[
paper=a4,                           % alle weiteren Papierformat einstellbar
fontsize=12pt,              % Schriftgröße (12pt, 11pt (Standard))
BCOR=5mm,                           % Bindekorrektur, bspw. 1 cm
DIV=calc,                           % führt die Satzspiegelberechnung neu aus
]

{scrbook}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{\baselineskip}     % oberer Seitenrand
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}                             % Absatzeinrückung
\setlength{\parskip}{1.25ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex}     % Absatzabstand
\setlength{\headheight}{1.3\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.05}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.65}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{repage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\let\amsboldsymbol\boldsymbol
\usepackage{bm}% ändert \boldsymbol
\let\boldsymbol\amsboldsymbol
\usepackage[textsize=small,obeyDraft]{todonotes}
\usepackage[version=4,layout=stacked]{mhchem}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{esvect}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\rmfamily}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\textbf{Gl.~\ref{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\reref}[1]{\textup{\textbf{\ref{#1}}}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcounter{reaction}
%%% >> for article <<
%\renewcommand\thereaction{C\,\arabic{reaction}}
%%% << for article <<
%%% >> for report and book >>
\renewcommand\thereaction{C\,\thechapter.\arabic{reaction}}
\@addtoreset{reaction}{chapter}
%%% << for report and book <<
\newcommand\reactiontag%
{\refstepcounter{reaction}\tag{\thereaction}}
\newcommand\reaction@[2][]%
{\begin{equation}\ce{#2}%
\ifx\@empty#1\@empty\else\label{#1}\fi%
\reactiontag\end{equation}}
\newcommand\reaction@nonumber[1]%
{\begin{equation*}\ce{#1}\end{equation*}}
\newcommand\reaction%
{\@ifstar{\reaction@nonumber}{\reaction@}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{How to force a special numbering with literals for a specific equation}

\begin{subequations}
      \begin{equation}
         1 + 3 = 4
        \label{eq:1plus3}
      \end{equation}
      \begin{equation}
         2 + 2 = 4 
        \label{eq:2plus2}
      \end{equation}
     \label{eq:result_equals_4}%
\end{subequations}

\begin{subequations}
       \reaction[react:NO2_a]{2 NO + O_2 <=> 2 NO_2 + 114,2\,\mathrm{\frac{kJ}{mol}}}
       \reaction[react:NO2_b]{NO + O <=> NO_2 + 306,3\,\mathrm{\frac{kJ}{mol}}}
       \label{react:NO2}%
 \end{subequations}

Result: \eqref{eq:1plus3} and \eqref{eq:2plus2} and \eqref{eq:result_equals_4}. \\
Result: \reref{react:NO2_a}, \reref{react:NO2_b}, \reref{react:NO2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in Maarten's edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code? Help us to help you!

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I have added a compilable code in my question above.

Comment: @Isabell: you can still give a try to the "code" button (with `{}` on it)... it's worth it `(-;`

Comment: @ ebo, sorry, I used the {} but I didn't get, that using ` code ` does not make the same like using ctrl + k...

Comment: Where did you find the `repage` package?

Comment: ftp://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf it's in the mhchem-package; there you can find the example how to label chemical reactions.

Comment: @Bernard: sorry, I got the question wrong. `repage` package is a simple style-file with custom page format adjustments, e. g. `\textwidth`, `\textheight` and `\oddsidemargin` written from a department at the university of munich, germany.

Comment: @Isabell: I see. I note my answer adds the chapter number before  the equation/reaction number. I suppose this is included in the specifications of `repage`, or must I modify my code so it behaves that way?

Comment: hm. in the `repage` package is no labeling defined (it's a good format-style for printing thesis double-sided). you have uncommanted the package in the answer below and it worked... so we don't know exactly, but we think its in the `scrpage2` or in `scrbook`.
sorry, maybe we have understood us wrong: in my example above, I didn't write C 1.1 ... but C 1.1 is the result I'd like to have - so everything is ok for my side! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution: I defined a clone of the `subequations` environment, under the name of `subreactions`:

```
\documentclass[
paper=a4, % alle weiteren Papierformat einstellbar
fontsize=12pt, % Schriftgröße (12pt, 11pt (Standard))
BCOR=5mm, % Bindekorrektur, bspw. 1 cm
DIV=calc, % führt die Satzspiegelberechnung neu aus
]
{scrbook}

\addtolength{\topmargin}{\baselineskip} % oberer Seitenrand
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm} % Absatzeinrückung
\setlength{\parskip}{1.25ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex} % Absatzabstand
\setlength{\headheight}{1.3\baselineskip}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.05}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.65}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\usepackage{repage}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\let\amsboldsymbol\boldsymbol
\usepackage{bm}% ändert \boldsymbol
\let\boldsymbol\amsboldsymbol
%\usepackage[textsize=small,obeyDraft]{todonotes}
\usepackage[version=4,layout=stacked]{mhchem}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{esvect}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\rmfamily}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\textbf{Gl.~\ref{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\reref}[1]{\textup{\textbf{\ref{#1}}}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcounter{reaction}
%%% >> for article <<
%\renewcommand\thereaction{C\,\arabic{reaction}}
%%% << for article <<
%%% >> for report and book >>
\renewcommand\thereaction{C\,\thechapter.\arabic{reaction}}
\@addtoreset{reaction}{chapter}
%%% << for report and book <<
\newcommand\reactiontag%
{\refstepcounter{reaction}\tag{\thereaction}}
\newcommand\reaction@[2][]%
{\begin{equation}\ce{#2}%
\ifx\@empty#1\@empty\else\label{#1}\fi%
\reactiontag\end{equation}}
\newcommand\reaction@nonumber[1]%
{\begin{equation*}\ce{#1}\end{equation*}}
\newcommand\reaction%
{\@ifstar{\reaction@nonumber}{\reaction@}}

\newcounter{parentreaction}% Counter for ``parent reaction''.
\@ifundefined{ignorespacesafterend}{%
  \def\ignorespacesafterend{\global\@ignoretrue}%
}{}
\newenvironment{subreactions}{%
  \refstepcounter{reaction}%
  \protected@edef\theparentreaction{\thereaction}%
  \setcounter{parentreaction}{\value{reaction}}%
  \setcounter{reaction}{0}%
  \def\thereaction{\theparentreaction\alph{reaction}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{reaction}{\value{parentreaction}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{How to force a special numbering with literals for a specific equation}

\begin{subequations}
      \begin{equation}
         1 + 3 = 4
        \label{eq:1plus3}
      \end{equation}
      \begin{equation}
         2 + 2 = 4
        \label{eq:2plus2}
      \end{equation}
     \label{eq:result_equals₄}%
\end{subequations}

\begin{subreactions}
       \reaction[react:NO2_a]{2 NO + O₂ <=> 2 NO₂ + 114,2\,\mathrm{\frac{kJ}{mol}}}
       \reaction[react:NO2_b]{NO + O <=> NO₂ + 306,3\,\mathrm{\frac{kJ}{mol}}}
       \label{react:NO2}%
 \end{subreactions}

Result: \eqref{eq:1plus3} and \eqref{eq:2plus2} and \eqref{eq:result_equals₄}. \\
Result: \reref{react:NO2_a}, \reref{react:NO2_b}, \reref{react:NO2}.

\end{document}
```

[image]