# Tag chemical equations with letters and numbers

Tags: environments, chemistry, mathematics

Just started in the writing of chemistry stuff using LaTeX.

**Question**

Is it possible to tag chemical equations with a letter and numbers as `R1`, `R2` and so on?

**Output and MWE**

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
      \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
        \usepackage{amssymb} 
        \usepackage{amsfonts}
        \usepackage{nccmath}
        \usepackage{chemformula}

 \begin{document}

    \begin{align}
    &\ch{B + H+ <=> BH+}\\
    &\ch{AH+ + B <=> A + BH^{+}} \label{reaccion_neta}
    \end{align}

    The sum \ref{reaccion_neta} is:

    \begin{align}
    \Delta G^0_{1} + \Delta G^0_{ref}&=-RT(ln(Ka_1)+ln(Ka^{-1}_{ref}) \\
    G^0_{BH^+} - G^0_{B} + G^0_{A}- G^0_{AH+} &=-RT(ln(Ka_1)+ln(Ka^{-1}_{ref})\\
    &= RT2.303pKa_{1}- RT2.303pKa_{ref}
    \end{align}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: We appreciate it if there is only one question per post. That allows us to keep focussed.

Comment: There are various packages for typesetting chemistry related stuff. You could have a look at `mhchem` or `chemmacros`. Both offer the possibility to align and number reaction equations. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147854/134144) might be interesting as well.

Comment: Unrelated: use `\ln` not `ln` for the natural logaritm, and you'd probably want `_{\mathrm{ref}}` instead of `_{ref}`.

Comment: How would you like the "letter numbering" to be relative to the "equation numbering"? (A) (B) (1) (2) (3)...?

Comment: `babel` seems to be responsible for that.

Comment: Would the ‘ordinary equations’ share the same counter, in other words, should we have  `chemeq (R1), equation (2),equation (3), chemeq (R4)` or   `chemeq (R1), equation (1),equation (2), chemeq (R2)`?

Comment: @Bernard no, separate numbering.  `chemeq(R1), equation(1),..`

Comment: @Hernan Miraola As already commented before, there already is an answer to this part of your question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147854/134144 Ludovic C. defined a new environment for numbering reaction  equations with R1... while keeping the counter of math equations untouched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are. I define an environment, somewhat like `subequations`, which re-defines the equation counter as a new `chemeqn` counter. Also, I propose another alignment (second group) based on `alignat`, which I find nicer:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
    \usepackage{chemformula}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{chemeqn}
\newenvironment{chemequations}{\let\c@equation\c@chemeqn\def\theequation{R\thechemeqn}}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{chemequations}
\begin{align}
     &\ch{B + H+<=> BH+}\\
     &\ch{AH+ + B<=> A + BH^{+}} \label{reaccion_neta}
\end{align}

\begin{alignat}{2}
    \ch{B &+ H+ & & <=> BH+}\\
    \ch{AH+ &+ B & & <=> A + BH^{+}} \label{reaccion_neta}
\end{alignat}
\end{chemequations}

The sum \eqref{reaccion_neta} is:
\begin{align}
\Delta G^0_{1} + \Delta G^0_\textrm{ref}&=-RT(\ln(Ka_1)+\ln(Ka^{-1}_\textrm{ref}) \\
G^0_{BH^+} - G^0_{B} + G^0_{A}- G^0_{AH+} &=-RT(\ln(Ka_1)+\ln(Ka^{-1}_\textrm{ref})\\
&= RT2.303pKa_{1}- RT2.303pKa_\textrm{ref}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]