# mathtools tagform labeling

Tags: labels, mathtools

So I'm using the lower version as in:
[How to force a special numbering for a specific equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147851/how-to-force-a-special-numbering-for-a-specific-equation)

switching between reactions and default with
\usetagform{reaction} and \usetagform{default}

The numbering however stays the same. Is it at least possible when refering to a `\label{R1}` with `\ref{R1}` to include the prefix R defined in the header
`\newtagform{reaction}[R]()`

Here is the MWE:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\newtagform{reaction}{(R}{)}

\begin{document}

\usetagform{reaction}
\begin{align}
    X + Y \quad \longrightarrow \quad Z \label{R1}
\end{align}

\usetagform{default}
\begin{align}
    x + y = z \label{eq2}
\end{align}

This is what I get:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item reaction (\ref{R1})
    \item equation (\ref{eq2})
\end{enumerate}


But I want:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item reaction ({\rm R}\ref{R1})
    \item equation (\ref{eq2})
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You may want to provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) such that others can reproduce your observation. And I'm wondering if `\newtagform{reaction}{(R}{)}` gives you what you want.

Comment: added the MWE...

Comment: No surprise. In the mathtools manual it is written that "When you reference an equation with \eqref, the tag form in effect at the time of refer- encing controls the formatting, so be careful if you use different tag forms throughout your document.".

Comment: Out of curiosity: do you know [`chemmacros`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) and its `reaction` environments?

Comment: No I dont, should i ?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**: Is this closer to what you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\PrependEqNo}[1]{\stepcounter{equation}\tag{#1\theequation}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    X + Y \quad &\longrightarrow \quad Z \PrependEqNo{R}
    \label{R1}\\
    A + B \quad &\longrightarrow \quad C \label{2}  
\end{align}
Above are reaction \eqref{R1} and equation \eqref{2}.
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
 U+V\quad &\longrightarrow \quad W\PrependEqNo{R}\\
 F+G\quad &\longrightarrow \quad H
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**OLD STUFF**: In the mathtools manual it is written that "When you reference an equation with \eqref, the tag form in effect at the time of refer- encing controls the formatting, so be careful if you use different tag forms throughout your document.". However, I think that the following might do what you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\newtagform{reaction}{(R}{)}


\newcommand{\SwitchToChem}{\renewcommand{\theequation}{R\arabic{equation}}}
\newcommand{\SwitchBack}{\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}}


\begin{document}

\usetagform{reaction}
\begin{align}
    X + Y \quad \longrightarrow \quad Z \label{R1}
\end{align}

\usetagform{default}
\begin{align}
    x + y = z \label{eq2}
\end{align}

This is what I get:
\begin{enumerate}
\usetagform{reaction}
    \item reaction \eqref{R1}
\usetagform{default}    
    \item equation \eqref{eq2}
\end{enumerate}

If you want to have this without switching, use 
\SwitchToChem
\begin{equation}
 U+W\quad\longrightarrow\quad V\label{R2}
\end{equation}
\SwitchBack
Here comes \eqref{R2}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is `\eqref` prefered over `\ref` ???

Comment: Also do I have to use "theequation" environment, or does the latter also work with align.
BTW: Why do you prefer: `{(R}{)}` over `[R]()`

Comment: @Diger `theequation` is not an environment, I just wrote  two options that were not explicitly discussed in the answers to (this question)[https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147851/how-to-force-a-special-numbering-for-a-specific-equation], and with `\newtagform{reaction}{(R}{)}` I just follow the mathtools manual.

Comment: Well the other answer however relies on the mhchem package...
I was wondering if using a new command like you I can do the same but with the align environment instead (is that an environment?)

Comment: @Diger So you want an align environment in which some numbers have an R in front and others not?

Comment: Yes, actually sth like `\newenvironment{chequation}{%
  \setcounter{temp}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{chem}}%
  \renewcommand{\theequation}{R\arabic{equation}}%
}{%
  \setcounter{chem}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{temp}}%
} `
is not too bad by I dont know why I need this mhchem package for that?
Do you know what the ~ infront of ~/ref is for?